# `window` is not defined - Angular CLI

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-cli

I need to use the global `window` object in an Angular 2 module, but the server side rendering done by Angular CLI means that `window` is undefined when the module is being processed.

How do I ensure that this particular module is processed on the client side, when `window` is available?

Thanks

Comment: I never used angular CLI, but AFAIK, it is a tool for project scaffolding. Why do you need the `window` global var to work with it?

Answer (score 0):

Please check if $window resolves the issue, it's a reference to the global window object - [*here* is the **doc link**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$window).

Comment: Sorry if it wasn't clear - I'm using Angular 2, not Angular 1